# On destroy with variables

Tags: angular

With the help of ngOnDestroy, does this mean that every variable you create within a component should be set to null using ngOnDestroy to prevent memory leaks? I understand you would definitely use it to destroy plugins such as audio players, but what about normal variables you've created yourself?

Answer (score 2):

No, those are managed by the component. It's generally used to clean up resources like event handlers or subscriptions that otherwise would cause memory leaks or lead unexpected behaviors if they held their reference.

Also see https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#ondestroy.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in the class will be garbage collected once the instance is destroyed. Things like this:

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {

  foo: number;

  @Input()
  bar: string; 
}
```

... will be cleaned up automatically (foo, bar).

What you need to be concerned about are asynchronous constructs like Subjects and Observables (and other stream/socket things ... sockJs, etc.). You need to make sure the streams are closed and unsubscribed on component destruction.

Worry about:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    someObservable.subscribe( val => doSomethignWithVal(val) ); // this subscription
  }
```